# HQL: Get objects that contain a certain number of elements in a list

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql

I'm struggling a little bit with an HQL select. I have a class Field that has a relation with another class called Base (one to many), so a field can have a set of bases.

I have to create a select so I can get the fields that has an exact number of bases. Here is my SQL select that is working:

```
select * from mydatabase.field c join mydatabase.base group by c.id having count(*) = 18;
```

But I don't know how to translate it to HQL. Could you help me?

Thanks

Comment: Leave out the `select *`?

Comment: Don't think it works without the select though...

Comment: You are correct that it doesn't work as an SQL statement, but we're not talking about SQL. HQL assumes `select *`, and doesn't accept a `select` clause, because it's usually going to populate an object's attributes with all the values from the table.